# Any way to use 'from' address from system.net/mailSettings/smtp in NLog mail target?

Tags: c#, email, nlog, system.net.mail

I'd like to send emails in case of some Fatal errors via NLog mail target.
I also have already configured **system.net/mailSettings/smtp** in web.config.

When I set `useSystemNetMailSettings="true"`, NLog uses everything from system.net/mailSettings/smtp except 'from' address. So I need to specify it one more time especially for mail target.

What i did? I've just created a variable "MailFrom" and initializing it programmatically when the application is started.

```xml
<nlog>
    <variable name="MailFrom" value=""/>
    <targets>
        <target name="mail" type="Mail" from="${var:MailFrom}" html="false" subject="Subject" to="ToList" useSystemNetMailSettings="true"/>
    </targets>
</nlog>
```

```cs
var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;
if (section != null)
    LogManager.Configuration.Variables["MailFrom"] = section.From;
```

maybe you know some better way of doing this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This option has been added to NLog 4.3.2.

---

PS: A prettier way is to use `FindTargetByName`:

```
 var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.net/mailSettings/smtp") as SmtpSection;
 if (section != null)
 {

     var mailtarget = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<MailTarget>("mail");
     if (mailtarget != null)
         mailtarget.From = section.From;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks good. The only change I had to do is to use AsyncTargetWrapper instead of MailTarget when getting the target.             var target = LogManager.Configuration.FindTargetByName<AsyncTargetWrapper>("mail"); 
var mailtarget = target.WrappedTarget as MailTarget;